# Why does the web service fail sometimes for the Stack API?

Tags: support, api

It seems to have happened all of the sudden. My calls to the web service fails. What is the limit of calls per day with a registered app? I can't seem to remember where it says that, I can't seem to find it. My website does not get that much traffic, not that I am aware of at the very least. I am going to diagnose the amount of calls, but is there any other reason why I would not receive anything? When I test locally on my dev machine, I can get the questions/answers, but on my production server it's failing (At least right now), but it doesn't always happen. And sometimes it fails all day and then in the evening it doesn't fail.

What could cause this? Can someone help me. Please let me know if I need to explain more details. :(

Comment: The details are [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).

Comment: Ok I had read that. So would you think that it's in the response that says "backoff"? I don't think there are 30 requests per second. I will analyze the data tonight, but if that's the case why would google do so many requests that quick? Because it always happens when google's web crawler is passing by my site.  Maybe now this is out of the scope of the question? I use the stacky api is there some thing that I can use there to find out more details?

Comment: You can use Google's Webmaster Tools to slow down the crawler as it goes through your site. I had a similar problem with StackMobile where Google was attempting to crawl hundreds of pages an hour.

Comment: I'm going to try that. Thanks for the tip. I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Okay so I did what you told me and it appeared to work for a while, but then I noticed that it happens when spammers are going through my page. I can't replicate the problem at all. What I did was created a console app that makes a call to the web service at an interval of 1 millisecond. The exact same call (so I made a timer that calls every millisecond...that didn't work and next I made the same timer call a new thread making the same call with the same interval of 1 millisecond between calls. Still the problem is not replicated. I am so confused on how to fix this problem. Any help?